# Decimal not showing leading zero

Tags: c#, epplus

I have the following code that formats a column as decimal
It works fine however if the number is less than 1 the zero is not displayed

```
foreach (var deciCol in decimalIndx)
   {
      var col = deciCol.Start.Column;
      sheet.Column(col).Style.Numberformat.Format = "#.####";
   }
```

> Input 12.35486 ==> in excel 12.3548 (OK)
>
> Input 0.34845 ==> in excel .3484 (0 is not displayed)
>
> Input 0 ==> in excel (**0.**) (how can i remove the decimal separator)?

Thank you in advance

**Edit:**

Thanks to the answer below, i used the following:

```
"0.0###"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`#` means `optional digit`. Use `0` for a leading zero, eg `"0.####"`.

The format string is the same format string you'd use in Excel if you selected a Custom format code. You can test the format string in Excel first and once you find the one you want, use it in EPPlus.

The contents of a custom numeric format string are documented in Excel's docs. Check [Create or delete a custom number format](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4). This explains how to specify different formats for positive, negative, zero amounts, include extra text etc.

It would seem that you can even specify colors in the format string. I wonder how `[Blue]0.###;[Red]-0.###` would look

**UDPATE**

As the linked page shows, you can specify a different format for zero, eg :

```
"0.####;-0.###;0"
```

Comment: Thank you, another issue is when the number is 0 it displays '0.'
how can i remove the decimal separator if the number is only 0?

Comment: @Maro if you check the linked page, it shows you can specify a different format for 0.

Comment: Ok thank you, i checked but there is nothing about removing the decimal separator however, i will use 0.0## to ensure there is a zero after the decimal separator .